# Get the actual text-content of pseudo-element content using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was able to get the text/content of pseudo-element content using `window.getComputedStyle('element', ':before').getPropertyValue('content');`. However, it returns a string enclosed in a double quote. I want it to return the actual string without the quotation so I tried to use `valueOf()` but it gave me the same result. I want to know if there's an existing method for that before I create my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are saying you already got the string, but with quotes, then do:

```js
var t = '"hello"'; // here put your text resulting from your prev code
console.log(t);

t = t.replace(/"/g, '');
console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are included to denote it is a literal string. This is necessary, because the CSS `content` attribute can contain expressions, like:

```
{ content: attr(class) }

{ content: "(" attr(class) ")" }
```

.. which will dynamically retrieve the element's `class` attribute and display that. In the second case it will be wrapped in parentheses.

When you retrieve the property value with `.getPropertyValue('content')` you will in fact get that expression as return value, which in the first case will be `attr(class)` without quotes.

Now, if you are certain that your property value is a string literal you can unwrap the string.

I would suggest:

```
JSON.parse(window.getComputedStyle('element', ':before').getPropertyValue('content'));
```